# Parent Select CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a css style to the **li element** that contains the **a element** with **attribute title** equals to **"Home"**

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Home">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="class" >2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"title="Home3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

I've tried with this selector but it doesn't work

```
li<a[title="Home"]{display:none;}
```

What css i should apply?
Thanks

Comment: not possible....https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/. Can you use jquery?

Comment: not possible as mentioned ^^ take a look into jQuery / JS

Comment: What in the world is `<`? I don't think browsers allow you to make up your own CSS selectors ;-)

Comment: I can't use jquery :( I can use only css unfortunately.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: There will/might be a [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector in the future, but it is still a draft.

Comment: Just try replacing `<` with `>`, take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uf861dj6/)

Comment: How to do it with jQuery?